# Reading .txt file from another directory

Tags: java, file-io, directory, text-files

The code I am running is in `/Test1/Example`.  If I need to read a .txt file in `/Test1`  how do I get Java to go back 1 level in the directory tree, and then read my .txt file

I have searched/googled and have not been able to find a way to read files in a different location.

I am running a java script in an .htm file located at /Test1/Test2/testing.htm.  Where it says script `src="    "`. What would I put in the quotations to have it read from my file located at `/Test1/example.txt`.

Comment: Try this - `../Test1/Example.txt`

Comment: I'd like to see the code you wrote

Comment: sounds like you are talking about Javascript, not Java?

Answer (score 2):

In Java you can use getParentFile() to traverse up the tree. So you started your program in /Test1/Example directory. And you want to write your new file as /Test1/Example.txt

```
    File currentDir = new File(".");
    File parentDir = currentDir.getParentFile();
    File newFile = new File(parentDir,"Example.txt");;
```

Obviously there are multiple ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the parent directory reference of "../"

You may need to do checks on the OS to determine which directory separation you should be using ['\' compared to '/']

Answer (score 1):

When you create a `File` object in Java, you can give it a pathname.  You can either use an absolute pathname or a relative one.  Using absolutes to do what you want would require:

```
File file = new File("/Test1/myFile.txt");
if(file.canRead())
{
    // read file here
}
```

Using relatives paths if you want to run from the location /Test1/Example:

```
File file = new File("../myFile.txt");
if(file.canRead())
{
    // read file here
}
```

Comment: What if I am running a java script in an .html document.
<script src= "What would I put here to make it read from my .txt file in /Test1?

Comment: @Jason - that is a different question entirely.  Might want to edit your question to clarify what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar experience.
My requirement is: I have a file named "sample.json" under a directory "input", I have my java file named "JsonRead.java" under a directory "testcase". So, the entire folder structure will be like untitled/splunkAutomation/src and under this I have folders input, testcase.

once after you compile your program, you can see a input file copy named "sample.json" under a folder named "out/production/yourparentfolderabovesrc/input" and class file named "JsonRead.class" under a folder named "out/production/yourparentfolderabovesrc/testcase". So, during run time, Java will actually refer these files and NOT our actual .java file under "src".

So, my JsonRead.java looked like this,

```
package testcase;
import java.io.*;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

public class JsonRead{
public static void main(String[] args){
java.net.URL fileURL=JsonRead.class.getClass().getResource("/input/sample.json");
System.out.println("fileURL: "+fileURL);
File f = new File(fileURL.toURI());
System.out.println("fileIs: "+f);
}
}
```

This will give you the output like,
fileURL: file:/C:/Users/asanthal/untitled/out/production/splunkAutomation/input/sample.json
fileIs: C:\Users\asanthal\untitled\out\production\splunkAutomation\input\sample.json

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me. I was saving all my classes on a folder but I needed to read an input file from the parent directory of my classes folder. This did the job.

```
String FileName = "Example.txt";

File parentDir = new File(".."); // New file (parent file ..)   
File newFile = new File(parentDir,fileName); //open the file
```