# how does one access a picture from within a jarfile? ie what would i use for a directory string?

Tags: java, eclipse, graphics, embedded-resource

Alright, so this is probably a really beginner problem here, but I've never actually used pictures inside my `src` folder. I always have linked my pictures to some folder like `C:\\Resource\\Logo.png`. I took a screenshot of how I've worked my directories. Basically I'm trying to get from `net.mousemaze.Textures.java` to `Resource.Font\FontA.png`.

[image: Location of font image]

Also, it may be worth noting that I am currently running on **fedora 17**.

the class that gets the images is pasted at
http://pastebin.com/KMVac7mg

also, the directories have been rearranged (screenshot updated) so i dont have to deal with going back a directory. Even so, it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the docs, there is a method called "createImageIcon"  which works within jar files:

```
/** Returns an ImageIcon, or null if the path was invalid. */
protected ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path,
                                           String description) {
    java.net.URL imgURL = getClass().getResource(path);
    if (imgURL != null) {
        return new ImageIcon(imgURL, description);
    } else {
        System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
        return null;
    }
}
```

See if you can edit that code to fit your purpose.

**Edit:** Link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html

Comment: i already have something like that in my code where it takes in a string and returns an image, however the problem im having is really what to enter as the directory string to get to Resource.Font from texture.java

Comment: So you want to go back a directory and then enter the Resource.Font directory? (Go back 1 level?) If so see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168515/java-reading-txt-file-from-another-directory

Comment: i have already tried that, it didn't work. thanks for the response though! :)

Comment: Hmm, then I am not sure what is wrong. Can you post the code that isn't working? Sorry that I couldn't help!

Comment: the question has been updated. That's alright, I thank you for trying!

Comment: AHA! alright so the first time i tried to use the bit of code you suggested i didn't exactly implementit correctly. so i retried it just using
java.net.URL imgURL = getClass().getResource("\\Resource\\TileSets\\TileBlueCoreV2.png");
g.drawImage(new ImageIcon(imgURL).getImage(), 100, 100, null);

and it worked great!
Thank you so much!! :D

Comment: just in case it may help some one else, the code i used after messing around with the code above is:
private BufferedImage getEmbeddedBufferedImage(String dir){
  java.net.URL imgURL = getClass().getResource(dir);
  Image img = new ImageIcon(imgURL).getImage();
  BufferedImage _return = createBufferedImage(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
  Graphics g = _return.getGraphics();
  g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
  return _return;
 }