# How do I read a file in a directory other than src?

Tags: java, java-io, java.nio.file

I have myFile.txt located in myJavaProject\webResources\sampleTransmissions. I am trying to read the file in myJavaProject\src\package1\notMyMainClass.java and I am having trouble building the path properly to access the webResources directory. Also, I would like to read the file using Files.readAllBytes(Path path) because I need to get non-printable characters to work with

edit: this would be my project structure

+myJavaProject

++src

+++notMyMainClass.java

++webResources

+++sampleTransmissions

++++myFile.txt

Comment: if you're using an idea you should be able to just right click the project, --> build path, ---> add class folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("webResources/sampleTransmissions/myFile.txt"));
```

This assumes that "myJavaProject" is your working directory. If you want it to work indepenently from the working directory, use an absolute path.

The forward slashes should work on Windows as well. If you prefer backslashes, you need to write `"webResources\\sampleTransmissions\\myFile.txt"`

Note: The working directory has nothing to do with the location of your .java or .class file.

Answer (score 0):

Think I found the answer to this question on another post..
[Reading .txt file from another directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168515/reading-txt-file-from-another-directory)

getParentFile() would be the way to do this.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/file_getparentfile.htm

```
File currentDir = new File(".");
File parentDir = currentDir.getParentFile();
File newFile = new File(parentDir,"Example.txt");;
```

Comment: I looked at that tutorialspoint link and I think it's a little different from my situation in that the variable declaration includes C:\. I can't do that, as this code base will have to work on other people's Eclipse workspaces, which may be god knows where. I need something a little more dynamic